# Automatically create street centerlines (axes) from inaccurate street lines and property bounds using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

Suppose we have street centerlines drawn inaccurately (e.g., OSM or PPGIS inputs) just as in the image below:

[image]

**Is there any automatic way in ArcGIS Pro to adjust the street centerlines to fall exactly between the property lines representing the access with the premise of being efficient?**

For example, a topologic rule could be set up to place the centerline exactly in the middle of the distance between the property line on both sides.

Comment: Of course it's possible. How many thousands of hours do you want to spend on the task?

Comment: I don't think I'll live that long. I am looking to automate this. For example, if there is a topologic rule to tell the distance to the property lines on both sides of each centerline should be equal, it could solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [ET_Geowizard](https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm), but with approximate centerlines already available you might use below workflow.

Erase envelope of your area by parcels to get road polygons. Clip streets by envelope and compute dangles, using feature vertices to point:

[image]

Snap dangles to outline of polygon and perhaps move some to a 'better' position on the line:

[image]

Split outline by dangle points and don't forget to merge 2 new segments touching start point of outline:

[image]

Compute Euclidean allocation to segments with max.distance equal widest road and road polygon (converted to raster) as mask:

[image]

Convert raster to polygons and polygons to line. Remove lines with LEFT_FID=-1. What remains are your new centerlines:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Could you please explain to me how I can achieve the same without the ET_GeoWizard plugin?

Comment: Workflow above works without GeoWizard, but you need advanced license and spatial analyst extension. No need to mark as solved if this is not working for you

Comment: The green check mark is not intended to indicate solved - it’s meant to be that it’s the answer that helped the asker the most.